# Consultation regarding a mysterious message on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The project worked fine for sudden I start getting the following message on Eclipse

`layout cannot be resolved or is not a field`

on this line:  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_comm);`

and this: `imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);`

i try this:

1. close & open Eclipse again
2. delete the R.java (and the Eclipse create a new one)
3. restart the computer
4. Project --> Clean
5. right click on my project --> Android Tools  --> Fix Project Properties

but nothing help

EDIT: and There is no error on xml files

Comment: arey they showing any lint warnings?

Answer (score 0):

There may be error in one of your xml files, because of that R.java is not getting created hence you are getting that error. check your xml files you will find error.